# How do I make a one of payment to my HSBC credit card bill with a HSBC debit card UK

Tags: credit-card, united-kingdom, online-banking, online-payment, direct-debit

I need to pay my HSBC credit card bill with a HSBC debit card and I can't transfer money between accounts (it doesn't show up on the list of accounts). When I click on the direct debit details it says I can make bespoke payments by clicking the 'Make a payment' quick link beside the debit card but it isn't there.

How do I make payments?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**I've only tried this on the UK HSBC website / updated May 2017**

After sitting on the phone for about a half hour I got instructions and want to share them to stop anyone else going through the same rigmarole I did.

First, you will need:

1. Your `Credit Card Number` (the long 16 digit one, no spaces, can be found on the dashboard under `My accounts`)
2. Your `Secure Login Key` (Your usual two factor auth key to login and make payments)

Follow these steps:

1. Login using the secure login key
2. Select the debit account you want to send money *from*. Click on the `Move money` link, select `New payment or transfer`
3. Click `New payee` and select `Payee lookup`
4. Type the first 6 digits of your credit card in the `Find a company` box. The drop-down menu should be filtered to a couple types of products. Choose your card type (example: `VISA HSBC`)
5. The `Company reference` number for the payment will be your 16 digit Credit Card number (no spaces)
6. Fill in the `Payment amount` that you want to pay and do the rest what the website says.
7. Generate the `transaction code` in the app (Generate Security Code) using the last 4 digits or your credit card.

It will save them in the list of past payment recipients when you click on the `Payments` link from the quick links on the dashboard view.

Hope this saved someone some time.

Comment: Why would you need your debit card number? And you're actually not paying with your debit card, you're making a bank transfer. It's coming from the same account in both cases, though.

Comment: Thanks. Saved my car rental (probably, says it arrives within 2 days & I'm kind of pushing the limit :)

Comment: thanks for the answer. Please give more detail in the 7.th step as it is not clear. HSBC app is like a maze with lots of traps. (: It`s like AAA game.  Need to master mechanics to advance in levels

Comment: This is a nightmare. HOW ARE WE SUPPOSED TO KNOW THAT? Anyway it's the only answer which worked for me, after reading a lot of things for +2h... Nice UX >< Thanks lededje for sharing!

Comment: Still more useful than the HSBC help page 3 years later...

Comment: @jag I wrote this 5 years ago! Glad it helped so many.

Answer (score 3):

I've just received my first credit card statement from HSBC. All I can say is all the information you need is there. It's really easy to pay off your credit card bill; you just have to read the instructions!

Here are the bank account numbers and steps how to set up a standing order (as it was written in my statement). Pay a fixed amount to your HSBC Bank credit card using the following information:

- Sort Code: 40-42-46
- Account Number: choose from the table below
- Reference: your 16 digit credit card number

```
 Type       Card Begins Account Number  
 ---------- ----------- -------------- 
 MasterCard   543460       29004734  
 Visa         454638       09003649  
 Gold Visa    494120       69005161
```

Remember, if payments are made using the wrong card details, sort code or account number, they may be delayed or not applied.

Comment: Above information works brilliantly. Others please try this.. Follow the instructions.. :-P

Answer (score 0):

Typically, a direct debit is set up by the company who will be *receiving* the money, not by you or your bank. So you need to contact your credit card company, and ask *them* to set up the direct debit.

Comment: Sorry; this infers a hsbc credit card. Typeically when you have a debit card and credit card from the same bank they offer an easy payment service. I'll update my answer

Comment: It may not matter. I have a credit card from the same bank where I have my bank account, and I still needed to set up a direct debit in order to pay it off automatically every month. Either way, probably simplest to phone HSBC and ask them.

Comment: Setting up a direct debit is easy enough with HSBC, but making one off payments is near impossible to work out from their website without ringing them.

Answer (score 0):

Very difficult to pay a credit card bill on a one off payment. Once you have selected HSBC card and used the secure key to confirm bill payment, in my experience it comes up error.mafter 3 attempts i was locked out of the account. Mush easier to use an account from another bank to pay the bill.

Answer (score 0):

just tried it and it worked well.
However I would like to add more info to be precise:
The above steps are correct between 1 and 5.

6. The reference number for the payment will be your 16 digit Credit Card number
7. fill in the amount what you want to pay and do the rest what the website says.

And that's it. It works well, however HSBC says that "your Credit Card balance won't be updated until the next working day". Actually it took 2 days for them to process it and I called them perhaps I made a mistake but everything went good and now my balance is zero (so give 48hours for them).

thank you for this write up ledeje.

Comment: "The above" may change over time.  Can you reference the author of the other or answer or copy their 1-5 steps into your answer?